# Missing Key Word in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to show all the customers with pending orders and the employees associated with these orders. But I keep getting a missing keyword error wherever I put my sub query.

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, OT.Date_Ordered, OT.Status, 
    CSR.EmployeeID, CSR.LastName, CSR.FirstName
FROM
    Customer C
JOIN 
    CreditCard CC ON C.CustomerID = CC.CustomerID
JOIN 
    Order_Table OT (SELECT OT.Status FROM Order_Table OT WHERE OT.Status = 'Pending') ON CC.CreditCard_Number = OT.CreditCard_Number
JOIN 
    CustomerService_Rep CSR ON CSR.EmployeeID = OT.EmployeeID 
GROUP BY 
    C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, OT.Date_Ordered, OT.Status, 
    CSR.EmployeeID, CSR.LastName, CSR.FirstName;
```

Comment: SELECT C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, OT.Date_Ordered, OT.Status, CSR.EmployeeID, CSR.LastName, CSR.FirstName
FROM Customer C
 JOIN CreditCard CC
 ON C.CustomerID = CC.CustomerID
 JOIN Order_Table OT (SELECT OT.Status FROM Order_Table OT WHERE OT.Status = 'Pending')
 ON CC.CreditCard_Number = OT.CreditCard_Number
 JOIN CustomerService_Rep CSR
 ON CSR.EmployeeID = OT.EmployeeID 
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, OT.Date_Ordered, OT.Status, CSR.EmployeeID, CSR.LastName, CSR.FirstName;

Comment: I guess you're not specifying the keys fot the join types (LEFT, INNER, RIGHT, ...)

Comment: What is your query supposed to do? You can't just stick a subquery anywhere; you're getting a syntax error because the database is expecting an `ON` keyword after `JOIN Order_Table OT` (also please tag which database you're using).

Comment: Your sub-query is completely out of place. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you're already joining on `Order_Table`, do you even need the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `where` clause in the outermost query:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, OT.Date_Ordered, OT.Status, 
       CSR.EmployeeID, CSR.LastName, CSR.FirstName
FROM Customer C JOIN
     CreditCard CC
     ON C.CustomerID = CC.CustomerID JOIN
     Order_Table OT 
     ON CC.CreditCard_Number = OT.CreditCard_Number JOIN
     CustomerService_Rep CSR
      ON CSR.EmployeeID = OT.EmployeeID 
WHERE OT.Status = 'Pending'
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, OT.Date_Ordered, OT.Status, CSR.EmployeeID, CSR.LastName, CSR.FirstName;
```

The subquery is not useful for this purpose.